# Bad request when performing a POST API query using webwrite

Tags: json, matlab, api, post, oauth-2.0

I'm attempting to create an App that exchanges information with an api (Questrade API to be precise). The api uses oauth2 for security and authentication.

I have been successful<sup>1</sup> in acquiring authorization tokens, refresh tokens and querying basic information (my account information and stock quotes).

However, I'm encountering an issue when I try to query stock option quotes (as described [here](https://www.questrade.com/api/documentation/rest-operations/market-calls/markets-quotes-options)).

I've tried many different permutations but to no avail. This is what I've done so far:

**1).**  I've taken the example shown in the "Sample Request" section provided in the link above and performed `jsondecode` to get the MATLAB equivalent and the "exact template" for which the parameter structure must be coded:

```
>> eg_param = jsondecode('{"filters":{"optionType":"Call","underlyingId":27426,"expiryDate":"2017-01-20T00:00:00.000000-05:00","minstrikePrice":70,"maxstrikePrice":80},"optionIds":[9907637, 9907638]}')

eg_param =     
  struct with fields:    
      filters: [1×1 struct]
    optionIds: [2×1 double]

>> eg_param.filters    
ans =     
  struct with fields:    
        optionType: 'Call'
      underlyingId: 27426
        expiryDate: '2017-01-20T00:00:00.000000-05:00'
    minstrikePrice: 70
    maxstrikePrice: 80

>> eg_param.optionIds    
ans =    
     9907637
     9907638
```

**2).** Substituted my actual values (`real_params`) for those in the example:

```
real_params.optionIds = 23255262;
real_params.filters.optionType = 'Call';
real_params.filters.expiryDate ='2018-11-09T00:00:00.000000-05:00';
real_params.filters.underlyingId = 40825;
real_params.filters.minstrikePrice = [];
real_params.filters.maxstrikePrice = [];
```

**3).** Changed `weboptions`' `RequestMethod` paramater to `post`

```
web_opt.RequestMethod = 'Post';
```

**4).** Used the `webwrite` function, as opposed to 'webread' to post and query the server:

```
new_data = webwrite(['https://api01.iq.questrade.com/',...
 'v1/markets/quotes/options'], real_params, web_opt);
```

However, when I do this, is get the error message:

```
*The server returned the status 400 with
message "Bad Request" in response to the
request to URL
https://api01.iq.questrade.com/v1/markets/quotes/options.*
```

I've tried many different permutations including changing brackets, [], {},{{}} and using different values for the parameters however the result is the same. Also, whenever I tested, I made sure to refresh the access token and test that the connection works using the "account info" request, so this error doesn't have to do with any authorization, security or connection issue.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, to acquire account information, which the [website](https://www.questrade.com/api/documentation/rest-operations/account-calls/accounts) instructs as:

```
GET https://api01.iq.questrade.com/v1/accounts
```

I've **1)**. used MATLAB's `weboptions` and created an object to store token information in `HeaderFields`:

```
web_opt = weboptions;
web_opt.RequestMethod = 'Get'; 
headerFields = {'Authorization', ['Bearer ', 'ZHHgMgh0up5UqJ9TSOIALpkoVpi0']};
web_opt.HeaderFields = headerFields;
```

and **2)**. queried the server using:

```
data = webread(['https://api01.iq.questrade.com/', 'v1/accounts'], web_opt);
```

And this accomplishes communication with the API server and MATLAB stores my account information as a structure array in the variable `data`.

Comment: Unfortunately I thought I added hyperlinks to the questions but they are not showing up in the original message.   The links are:
[website][1] - https://www.questrade.com/api/documentation/rest-operations/account-calls/accounts

(as described [here][2]. - https://www.questrade.com/api/documentation/rest-operations/market-calls/markets-quotes-options

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot test the solution since the API key you provided seems not to work, but it might help you anyway.

Can you spot the difference between the JSON produced using these two blocks?

```
% Original code:
real_params.optionIds = 23255262;
real_params.filters.optionType = 'Call';
real_params.filters.expiryDate ='2018-11-09T00:00:00.000000-05:00';
real_params.filters.underlyingId = 40825;
real_params.filters.minstrikePrice = [];
real_params.filters.maxstrikePrice = [];
%{
>> jsonencode(real_params)
ans =
    '{"optionIds":2.3255262E+7,"filters":{"optionType":"Call","expiryDate":"2018-11-09T00:00:00.000000-05:00","underlyingId":40825,"minstrikePrice":[],"maxstrikePrice":[]}}'
%}
```

```
% Slightly modified code:
real_params = struct();
real_params.optionIds = int32(23255262);
real_params.filters.optionType = 'Call';
real_params.filters.expiryDate ='2018-11-09T00:00:00.000000-05:00';
real_params.filters.underlyingId = 40825;
real_params.filters.minstrikePrice = [];
real_params.filters.maxstrikePrice = [];    
%{
>> jsonencode(real_params)
ans =
    '{"optionIds":23255262,"filters":{"optionType":"Call","expiryDate":"2018-11-09T00:00:00.000000-05:00","underlyingId":40825,"minstrikePrice":[],"maxstrikePrice":[]}}'
%}
```

It might be that the automatic conversion is the culprit in this case (which for a lack of better reason, sent your `optionIds` as a `double` value, and not the integer that the API expects.